# Expression.Error: We cannot convert a value of type Function to type Text

Tags: formula, powerquery, m

This M (Power Query) function gives this error "Expression.Error: We cannot convert a value of type Function to type Text."
The Function Objective is having two Text Input and subtracting them to durations (as list or text)

For Example:

- 1/20/2020 1:49:46 PM, 1/20/2020 1:58:03 PM, 1/20/2020 2:09:42 PM
- 1/20/2020 1:49:41 PM, 1/20/2020 1:57:58 PM, 1/20/2020 2:09:38 PM

```fs
let 
    Source = (txtCheckInTime as text, txtCheckOutTime as text) as text =>
        let
            lstCheckinTimeLst = Text.Split(txtCheckInTime, ", "),
            lstCheckOutTimeLst = Text.Split(txtCheckOutTime, ", "),
            txtCheckInEvent = each lstCheckinTimeLst,
            txtCheckOutEvent = each lstCheckOutTimeLst,
            EventDuration = DateTime.FromText(txtCheckInEvent) - DateTime.FromText(txtCheckOutEvent),
            Source = Text.Combine(Duration.ToText(EventDuration), ", ")
        in
            Source
in
    Source
```

Could anyway point out the error?

Comment: the following two lines are the culprit: txtCheckInEvent = each lstCheckinTimeLst,
        txtCheckOutEvent = each  lstCheckOutTimeLst,

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues going on here.

1. The main issue is because the `each` keyword is a placeholder for an *iterative function*, not an iterator itself (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/understanding-power-query-m-functions) for details).
2. The `DateTime.FromText()` function requires a single element, not a list or function object (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/datetime-fromtext) for details).
3. It appears like in your sample data, the `CheckInTime`'s are *after* the `CheckOutTime`'s?

If I were to re-write your function, this is what it would look like:

```fs
let fun_GetDurations = (txt_CheckInTime as text, txt_CheckOutTime as text) as text =>
  let
    lst_CheckInTime = Text.Split(txt_CheckInTime, ", "),
    lst_CheckOutTime = Text.Split(txt_CheckOutTime, ", "),
    tbl_Times = Table.FromColumns({lst_CheckInTime, lst_CheckOutTime}, {"CheckInTime", "CheckOutTime"}),
    fix_Formatting = Table.TransformColumns(tbl_Times, {{"CheckInTime", each DateTime.FromText(_, "en-US"), type nullable text}, {"CheckOutTime", each DateTime.FromText(_, "en-US"), type nullable text}}),
    add_Duration = Table.AddColumn(fix_Formatting, "Duration", each Duration.ToText([CheckOutTime] - [CheckInTime]), type text),
    get_Durations = Text.Combine(Table.Column(add_Duration, "Duration"), ", ")
  in
    get_Durations
in fun_GetDurations
```

And then when you check it:

```fs
let
  txt_CheckInTime = "1/20/2020 1:49:41 PM, 1/20/2020 1:57:58 PM, 1/20/2020 2:09:38 PM",
  txt_CheckOutTime = "1/20/2020 1:49:46 PM, 1/20/2020 1:58:03 PM, 1/20/2020 2:09:42 PM",
  Durations = fun_GetDurations(txt_CheckInTime, txt_CheckOutTime)
in
  Durations
```

You get the results expected:

```fs
00:00:05, 00:00:05, 00:00:04
```